# How to call djangos get_absolute_url method?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing a web application using Django, I got started to use Class View and used the `get_absolute_url` method  without knowing how it is triggered. I have checked Django's documentation, unfortunately could not find nothing about that. Could someone explain? It seems that when the user is created, the `get_absolute_url` method is triggered automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called by class-based views like a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) and [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) and other views that make use of the [**`ModelFormMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin).

This mixin overrides the [**`get_success_url(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) as follows:

> Determine the URL to redirect to when the form is successfully validated. Returns `django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.success_url` if it is provided; **otherwise, attempts to use the `get_absolute_url()` of the object**.

So if you do not provide a `success_url` attribute in your view, or you do not override the `get_success_url` method of the view yourself. Django will use the `get_absolute_url()` method of the object you constructed, updated, etc. in the view. This is [implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L110-L121):

> ```
>     def get_success_url(self):
>         """Return the URL to redirect to after processing a valid form."""
>         if self.success_url:
>             url = self.success_url.format(**self.object.__dict__)
>         else:
>             try:
>                 url = self.object.get_absolute_url()
>             except AttributeError:
>                 raise ImproperlyConfigured(
>                     "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define"
>                     " a get_absolute_url method on the Model.")
>         return url
> ```

The succes url is used to redirect to in case of a *succesful* POST request. For example the form you filled in in a `CreateView` is valid, and resulted in the creation of a record that the database.